# Request.Files - get the first File without foreach cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in web. This is my `action`:

```
[HttpPost]
 public virtual ActionResult SaveFile(IEnumerable<VacationSchedule.Models.VacationTypeViewModel> vacationTypes)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                string type = file.ContentType;
                string nameAndLocation = "~/Documents/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(nameAndLocation));
            }      
            return View(MVC.Admin.ActionNames.Documents);
        }
```

Question: I know that in the Request.Files can be only one file. Is exist any way to get this File without `foreach` cycle?

Comment: how about using indexer ? `Request.Files[0]` ?

Comment: You should use `Single()` if you expect it to be exactly 1 file

Comment: Thanks, Selman. That was really easy.

Comment: Personally I'd use SingleOrDefault()

Comment: Single() is not good. It will throw the Exception if there is no File in Array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method:

```
 string fileName = Request.Files.Cast<HttpPostedFile>().FirstOrDefault();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
{
}
```

Or simply the ternary operator with the index accessor:

```
string fileName = Request.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Files[0] : null;
```

Comment: `Request.Files` does not have a `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Josh You are right. I missed the cast since it implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFile>`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the index/key of first element with the name of file:

```
var imagem = Request.Files[Request.Files.GetKey(0)];
```